# Get and display site description from json on a react website

Tags: reactjs, json, meta-tags

How do I get the description value from json here to display as the site description?

[image]

I have been able to access the site title and favicon but can't figure out how to access and display the site description. My code:

```
import App from "next/app";
import Head from "next/head";
import { AppProps } from "next/app";

import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";

import { ContextProvider } from "../store/context";
import { ManagedUIContext } from "../components/UX/context";

import useFetchContent from "@utils/useFetchContent";

//styles
import { GlobalStyle } from "../styles/styles";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }: AppProps) {
  const { global } = pageProps;

  console.log(global);

  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <ManagedUIContext>
        <Head>
          <link
            rel="shortcut icon"
            type="image/png"
            href={global.favicon.url}
          />
          <title>{global.title}</title>
          <meta name="description" content={global.description}></meta>  
        </Head>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
      </ManagedUIContext>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  // Calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  // Fetch global site settings from Contentful
  const globalData = await useFetchContent(`
  {
    globalCollection {
      items {
        favicon {
          url
        }
        title
        description {
          json
        }
      }
    }
  }
`);
  const global = globalData.globalCollection.items[0];
  // Pass the data to our page via props
  return { ...appProps, pageProps: { global } };
};
```

The idea here is to get the site title and description from contentful so that google uses these to generate the snippet for search results. At the moment I'm able to get the title and see it on google snippet. But can't figure out how to do the same for the description. And regarding the meta tag for the description is my approach the correct one?